# Why javascript setTimeout delay is not working and setInterval is too slow

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, settimeout, setinterval

```
    function paint(ctx, canvas) {
    var veces = 0;
    var interval = 1000;
    dibujo();
    function dibujo() {
        var lado1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1);
        var lado2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 300) + 1);
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
        ctx.strokeRect((canvas.width / 2) - (lado1 / 2),
            (canvas.height / 2) - (lado2 / 2),
            lado1,
            lado2);
        veces++;
        if (veces < 1000) {
            setTimeout(dibujo(), interval);
        }
    }
}
```

My complete code for setTimeout [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gsubiran/HB5Br/)

and

My complete code for setInterval [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gsubiran/G6ZyS/)

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `setTimeout` improperly:

```
    setTimeout(dibujo, interval); // no ()
```

You have to pass a reference to your function, which is accomplished by using the name of the function. You don't want `()` because that causes the function to be called *before* the call to `setTimeout` happens, with the return value of your function passed in instead of a reference to the function.

Answer (score 2):

Just in addition to Pointy's answer. Because of the single threaded architecture of js, you will never get 0ms steps in a setInterval, in some browsers this will get close to 0 ms but it will never be the same as a loop which looks down the browser until its finished.

In my **chrome it is an average of 5.3ms** and in my **IE10 an average of 3.4ms**. Maybe that is what you meant with "*setInterval is too slow*".